# NumPy - Advancing Random BitGenerator

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to work on a script that, regardless of the count of execution threads/processes I'm using, I'll be able to generate the same dataset of random data deterministically. As the dataset is for consumption by a relational database by means of a csv file(s), row order is not important.

The logic I have been working on is to split the work among *n* workers, and advance the BitGenerator of the Generator object accordingly. For example, if I want to generate 1000 rows, below will output the equivalent dataset:

- 1 process generating all 1000 rows.
- 2 processes (p1 and p2):

  - p1 generating rows from 1-500;
  - p2 generating rows from 501-1000, with the BitGenerator advanced by 500.

Python standard `random.Random()` object does not allow to select the BitGenerator, and the default is `MT19937` which can't be advanced anyway.

I have been thus looking at NumPy objects [Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) and [BitGenerators](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html) and they are very helpful, however, I run into below issue. First however, this is my env:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

print(sys.version)
print(np.__version__)
```

```
3.9.9 (v3.9.9:ccb0e6a345, Nov 15 2021, 13:29:20) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
1.22.0
```

I have been doing these tests with `PCG64`, `PCG64DXSM` and `Philox`, but the result is similar. What I see is that I can't correctly predict by how much I have to advance the BitGenerator to make sure I get the expected result. See example below:

```py
bitgen = np.random.PCG64(seed=0)
rng = np.random.Generator(bitgen)

for i in range(6):
    print(i, rng.random())

print("-------------------------")

# repeat, advance the bitgen by 1
bitgen = np.random.PCG64(seed=0).advance(1)
rng = np.random.Generator(bitgen)

for i in range(5):
    print(i, rng.random())
```

See how rows 1-5 of the first group match with 0-4 of the second group. They correctly advanced by 1.

```
0 0.6369616873214543

1 0.2697867137638703
2 0.04097352393619469
3 0.016527635528529094
4 0.8132702392002724
5 0.9127555772777217
-------------------------
0 0.2697867137638703
1 0.04097352393619469
2 0.016527635528529094
3 0.8132702392002724
4 0.9127555772777217
```

However, other random functions don't behave the same. Below the output of the above script substituting `rng.random()` with `rng.integers(1000)` and `rng.bytes(1)`.

Notice in both cases how the values start matching after 2 rows, not one.

Output using `integers(1000)`:

```
0 850
1 636

2 511
3 269
4 307
5 40
-------------------------
0 511
1 269
2 307
3 40
4 75
```

Output using `bytes(1)`:

```
0 b'_'
1 b'\xcf'

2 b'!'
3 b'\xf8'
4 b'\xb8'
5 b'\xa9'
-------------------------
0 b'!'
1 b'\xf8'
2 b'\xb8'
3 b'\xa9'
4 b'\x1d'
```

Tricky outputs are also seen when the output is an array. Function `rng.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])` correctly shifts the number by 1, but the array result per se is not what I wanted: in below, the number start matching after 1 value, but the arrays are all wrong!

```
0 [3 2 0]
1 [0 3 3]
2 [3 3 3]
3 [3 3 0]
4 [3 0 3]
5 [2 3 3]
-------------------------
0 [2 0 0]
1 [3 3 3]
2 [3 3 3]
3 [3 0 3]
4 [0 3 2]
```

Given the complexity, it seems there is no easy solution for this?

Parallel execution to reproduce the same dataset is possible IF AND ONLY IF then number of threads/processes remains the same, as per docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/multithreading.html), but this was not the intention.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're parallelising over rows, I'd suggest using [`SeedSequence`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.SeedSequence.html)`.spawn_key` to keep determinism within rows.  For example, doing:

```
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64, SeedSequence

seed = 42

for row in range(7):
  g = Generator(PCG64(SeedSequence(seed, spawn_key=[row])))
  print(g.random())
```

This way you don't need to worry about knowing how many "random values" are consumed by each generator invocation.

Maybe a more verbose example would help:

```
def make_row(row_num):
  g = Generator(PCG64(SeedSequence(seed, spawn_key=[row_num])))
  return g.random()

# one process
for i in range(1000):
  print(make_row(i))

# multiple processes:
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
  pool.map(make_row, range(1000))
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, I had looked into SeedSequence but that only works if and only if the number of threads/procs is the same on every run. That was the intention of my last sentence.

Comment: where do you see that?  note that I'm not suggesting using the `spawn` function, but using the `spawn_key` directly.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not understanding. I've tried creating 2 generators like you suggested, however I don't get the same as with `advance`. The outputs don't overlap after 1 row. Sorry doesn't format well...

```python
g1 = Generator(PCG64(SeedSequence(seed, spawn_key=[0])))
g2 = Generator(PCG64(SeedSequence(seed, spawn_key=[1])))

for _ in range(5):
    print(g1.random())

for _ in range(5):
    print(g2.random())
```

Comment: I don't think you can (reliably) use `advance` to solve your problem, hence my suggestion of seeding a new RNG each row